# Filling missing values in Pandas dataframe using another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like:

```
Race_ID   Date           Student_ID      Rank  Student_Name 
1         1/1/2023       1               3     Ryan
1         1/1/2023       NaN             2     Mary
1         1/1/2023       3               1     Tony
1         1/1/2023       4               4     Chris
2         11/9/2022      1               2     Ryan
2         11/9/2022      NaN             3     Mary
2         11/9/2022      3               1     Tony
3         17/4/2022      5               4     Josh
3         17/4/2022      NaN             1     Mary
3         17/4/2022      3               2     Tony
3         17/4/2022      4               3     Chris
4         1/3/2022       1               1     Ryan
4         1/3/2022       NaN             2     Mary
5         1/1/2021       1               2     Ryan
5         1/1/2021       NaN             3     Mary
5         1/1/2021       3               1     Tony
```

The Student_ID for Mary is missing. However I have another dataframe `studentList` that looks like

```
Studnet_ID   Student_Name
1            Ryan
2            Mary
3            Tony
4            Chris
5            Josh
6            David
7            Evan
```

which I want to use to fill in the `NaN` in the `Student_ID` column in `df`. Is there any quick way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since ID is missing only in case of `Mary`, the following solution should work.

```
df1['Student_ID'] = df1['Student_ID'].fillna(df2[df2['Student_Name']=='Mary'].Student_ID[1])
```

If there are no specific student's name, then the following solution should work:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'Student_Name', how = 'left', suffixes = ('', '_test'))
df3['Student_ID'] = df3['Student_ID'].fillna(df3.Student_ID_test).astype(int)
```

Final Result in both cases:

```
Race_ID       Date  Student_ID  Rank Student_Name
0         1   1/1/2023         1.0     3         Ryan
1         1   1/1/2023         2.0     2         Mary
2         1   1/1/2023         3.0     1         Tony
3         1   1/1/2023         4.0     4        Chris
4         2  11/9/2022         1.0     2         Ryan
5         2  11/9/2022         2.0     3         Mary
6         2  11/9/2022         3.0     1         Tony
7         3  17/4/2022         5.0     4         Josh
8         3  17/4/2022         2.0     1         Mary
9         3  17/4/2022         3.0     2         Tony
10        3  17/4/2022         4.0     3        Chris
11        4   1/3/2022         1.0     1         Ryan
12        4   1/3/2022         2.0     2         Mary
13        5   1/1/2021         1.0     2         Ryan
14        5   1/1/2021         2.0     3         Mary
15        5   1/1/2021         3.0     1         Tony
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to merge:

```
df = df.merge(studentList, left_on='Student_Name', right_on='Student_Name', how = 'left')
```